# Finding record that has MAX time-stamp on inner join

Tags: mysql

I may be looking at this all wrong, but I have this problem in MySQL: I have a table that can have multiple results and I want to get the max timestamp.

I have this query at present:

```
LEFT JOIN heartbeat_activity hbco ON jid.field_application_job_id_nid = hbco.nid_target
AND hbco.uid_target = n.uid
AND hbco.message_id = 'heartbeat_call_in_confirm'
LEFT JOIN heartbeat_activity hbci ON jid.field_application_job_id_nid = hbci.nid_target
AND hbci.uid_target = n.uid
AND hbci.message_id = 'heartbeat_call_in_requested'
LEFT JOIN heartbeat_activity hbrj ON jid.field_application_job_id_nid = hbrj.nid_target
AND hbrj.uid_target = n.uid
AND hbrj.message_id = 'heartbeat_call_in_rejected'
```

On the above, `joins` through `heartbeat_activity` can have multiple records with differing timestamps, so I would like to do something like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT MAX(TIMESTAMP) AS TIMESTAMP,
                nid_target,
                uid_target
FROM heartbeat_activity
WHERE message_id = 'heartbeat_call_in_confirm'
GROUP BY uaid
```

But doing this on each join is expensive, as it's selecting on all the records. What's the best way of going about this?

Comment: You might have to do two selects. One to get ALL last timestamps for all uids. And the second one to gather all your data (as above) but with a WHERE filter on the ids you got in your first select.

Sometimes joining is much faster in your app than in your SQL db.

Comment: Could a series of simple CASE statements avoid all those JOINs?